# how to check all checkboxes and keep them checked through pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, checkbox

I have the scripts below one which checks all checkboxes in a group which works great, and another to pass the checkbox values over the pagination and all works fine the only problem is that when I click the check all box it checks all the pages on page 1 but when I click page 2 only the check all box is checked although the query is working fine. If I click all the checkboxes individually then they pass through the pagination fine, so I don't know why the check all button doesn't. I would like it so that when you click check all, all the boxes stay checked through the pagination as well.

here is my script that checks all checkboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           window.addEvent('domready', function() {
     $$('li.head input[type=checkbox]').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.getParent('ul').getElements('input[type=checkbox]').setProperty('checked',  this.checked);
});
 });
  </script>
```

here is the script that remembers the checkboxes

```
     var aa_checkbox;

      function init_checkbox(){
      //setup blank cb cookie
 if(!Cookie.read('cb')){
 Cookie.write('cb', JSON.encode({}));
  }

     //setup "associative array" to match what is currently in the cookie
   aa_checkbox = JSON.decode(Cookie.read('cb'));


//set up each checkbox with class="remember_cb"
 $$('input.remember_cb').each(function(el){

  //mark checked if it is in the cookie
  if(aa_checkbox[el.name]){
  el.checked = 'checked'
  }

  //setup onclick event to put checkbox status in the 
  el.addEvent('click', function(){
    if(el.checked){
    aa_checkbox[el.name] = 1;
    }else{
    delete(aa_checkbox[el.name]);
   }   
  }) 
 })

//save aa_checkbox back into cookie upon leaving a page
window.onbeforeunload = function(){Cookie.write('cb', JSON.encode(aa_checkbox));};

 setup_form();

return true;
 }

  function setup_form(){
 //set up form so that it adds the inputs upon submit.
 $$('form.remember_cb_form').each(function(form){
  form.addEvent('submit', function(ev){
   //clean up previously inserted inputs
   var aa_hidden_insert = $$('input.hidden_insert');
   $each(aa_hidden_insert, function(el){ 
     el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
   })

   var el_form = this;

   //insert hidden elements representing the values stored in aa_checkbox
   $each(aa_checkbox, function(i_value, s_name){
     if(i_value){ 
      var el_input = document.createElement('input');
      el_input.type = 'hidden';
      el_input.value = i_value;
      el_input.name = s_name;
      el_input.setAttribute('class', 'hidden_insert');
      el_form.appendChild(el_input);
    }
  });
});
  });
}

 window.addEvent('domready', init_checkbox);
```

If anyone can help me I would be very greatful, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how your code works. I recommend that the check/un-check should affect the in-memory copy of the backing data. EG if you have an array representing the check boxes, set the check/uncheck in the array then render the array to check/uncheck the corresponding check box. That way, when you check all, all the array cells are set to checked! When you change from page to page, simply read the status of the corresponding array cell.